# Sound stops on internal speaker after a while and comes back after starting ubuntu installer under live usb

Tags: sound, headphones

I encountered a strange problem with sound - it disappears after a few seconds of playback on internal laptop speaker. It does not happen while using external speaker via mini jack connection. To confirm it's not hardware problem I booted into live-usb Ubuntu 20.04 and got the same effect BUT noticed that opening and closing build-in Ubuntu installer (the first icon in left hand side dock) somehow makes the sound comeback. Is there anything special in this installer executed before the language select dialog that could possibly fix sound issues?